# swift: how to TTS all cell on click button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, text-to-speech

I have a UITextView in UITableViewCell of multiple cells: 
all cells textView's text is needed to convert form text to speech(TTS) on click UIButton. 
The UIButton is in UITableViewCell. 
Now all cell's textview's text is not being converted from text to speech on button's click. Just one textView's text is converted on button's click

**UITableViewCell**

```
class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  var homeViewCon: HomeTableViewController?
  let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

  @IBAction func ttsBtnClick(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let ttsBtnCheck = sender as? UIButton else {
        return
    }

    if ttsBtnCheck.isSelected {
        ttsBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "tts"), for: .normal)
        ttsBtnCheck.isSelected = false
        synth.stopSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
    } else{
        print("ttsBtnClick false ")
        ttsBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "ttsBlue"), for: .selected)
        ttsBtnCheck.isSelected = true

        textToSpeech()

        let point = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.homeViewCon?.homeTableView)
        let indexPath = self.homeViewCon?.homeTableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)!

        let indexPathRow  = indexPath?.row ?? 0
        let indexPathSection = self.homeViewCon?.homeTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: (indexPath?.section)!)

        if indexPathRow < indexPathSection! {
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row:(indexPath?.row)! + 1, section:(indexPath?.section)!)
            self.homeViewCon?.homeTableView.scrollToRow(
                at: newIndexPath as IndexPath, at:.bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }

}


func textToSpeech(){


    let name: String = newsTextView.text
    let endIndex = name.index(name.endIndex, offsetBy: -3)
    let truncated = name.substring(to: endIndex)



    let index2 = truncated.range(of: ".", options: .backwards)?.lowerBound

    var substring3 = index2.map(truncated.substring(to:))


    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: titleLabel.text!+". "+substring3!)

    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")


    synth.speak(utterance)

}
}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: @ReinierMelian i want to tts all cell after click UIButton

Comment: all cellsssssss not only relevant cell button ????

Comment: @Sh_Khan you are write. what i have to do now

Comment: you already have required text as you are displaying it in tableview. Just loop the array containing text and do TTS for that text do not take text from a particular textview on buttons click. Use the array to get all the text for TTS

Answer (score 1):

Please find working solution along with storyboard UI.

**Swift 4**

```
    //
    //  TableViewVC.swift
    //
    //  Created by Test User on 06/02/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

    class customCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var lblTTS: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var btnTTS: UIButton!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
        }

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        }
    }

    class TableViewVC: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var tblTTS: UITableView!


        var arrTTS = [
            "This is first text",
            "This is second text",
            "This is third text",
            "This is fourth text",
            "This is fifth text",
            "This is sixth text",
            "This is seventh text",
            "This is eighth text",
            "This is ninth text",
            "This is tenth text",
            "This is eleventh text",
            "This is twelfth text",
        ]

        let speechSynthesizer                       = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        var previousSelectedIndexPath              : IndexPath?


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            speechSynthesizer.delegate = self
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

        @IBAction func btnTTSClicked(sender: UIButton) {

            let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tblTTS)
            let indexPath = self.tblTTS.indexPathForRow(at: point)

            if previousSelectedIndexPath == indexPath {

                let cell = self.tblTTS.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! customCell
                speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
                cell.btnTTS.setTitle("TTS", for: .normal)
                previousSelectedIndexPath = nil

            } else {

                if previousSelectedIndexPath == nil {

                    previousSelectedIndexPath = indexPath

                    let cell = self.tblTTS.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! customCell
                    cell.btnTTS.setTitle("Speaking", for: .normal)

                    if speechSynthesizer.isSpeaking {

                        speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)

                    } else {

                        let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: self.arrTTS[indexPath!.row])

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
                        }
                    }

                } else {

                    let oldCell = self.tblTTS.cellForRow(at: previousSelectedIndexPath!) as! customCell
                    oldCell.btnTTS.setTitle("TTS", for: .normal)

                    let cell = self.tblTTS.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! customCell
                    cell.btnTTS.setTitle("Speaking", for: .normal)

                    previousSelectedIndexPath = indexPath

                    if speechSynthesizer.isSpeaking {

                        speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)

                    } else {

                        let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: self.arrTTS[indexPath!.row])

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    extension TableViewVC: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return arrTTS.count
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! customCell

            cell.lblTTS.text = self.arrTTS[indexPath.row]
            cell.btnTTS.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTTSClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            return cell
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 50
        }
    }

    extension TableViewVC: AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

        func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {

            speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .word)

            if previousSelectedIndexPath != nil {
                let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: self.arrTTS[previousSelectedIndexPath!.row])
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Minzu did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: tts is being just first line repeatedly after use your code

Comment: Means can you please elaborate ?

Comment: i have a tableView with infinite scrolling. i want to do tts all cell values on click button. after click button it will be scroll automatically and also tts all cell values automatically.

Comment: As per my current implementation i have added TTS button in all cell, Whatever cell TTS button you will tap it's text will convert to speech and that speech will play.

Comment: that was not issue. my issue was tts will continue all cell values on click button

Comment: Please find working demo as per your exact requirement: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ou1fgk7oeu78r23/SOFTableViewPaging.zip?dl=0

I would appreciate if you could accept my answer!

Comment: i put UIButton in UITableViewCell. but you put in navigationBar. i wanted to start tts from which cell user choose. next i will continue tts at bottom. my tableView two dimension array. please help me.

Comment: It's pretty simple thing You can use your logic if you can.

Comment: After accepting my answer you have unaccepted it just for 5% of your exact requirement remaining work, It's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that not all cells are visible during you click the button on one of them so while user enters text in the textView and scroll the text is lost so , so implement `didEndDisplaying`  to store the current textView's text in the a global array and when cell button clicked loop through the array contents and do tts for every text

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell,forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: what i have to write in this fiction please help me

Comment: access the cell tectView text and store it in the relevant index of the global array that will save your text when user scrolls

Comment: i want to do the scroll automatically after click button

Comment: it will be scroll and tts automatically one by one at bottom after click UIButton

Comment: content of textviews cells is pre setter in cellforrow ?